# What's the etymology of "times interest earned ratio"?

Tags: terminology

Gill, Madura. [*Personal Finance*, 4th Canadian Edition 2019](https://www.amazon.ca/Personal-Finance-Canadian-Pearson-Package/dp/013485201X/ref=pd_cp_14_1?pd_rd_w=c29n6&pf_rd_p=64a84aa4-b549-4445-9bf3-48bdeed5f24a&pf_rd_r=82BZKGBE1YW3BZXRTA41&pd_rd_r=ac94fdf8-0331-4f63-9fd4-08392967896d&pd_rd_wg=LkHyc&pd_rd_i=013485201X&psc=1&refRID=82BZKGBE1YW3BZXRTA41). p 335. Emboldenings are mine.

> Thus, a more appriopriate measure of the firm's ability to repay its debt is the **times interest earned ratio**, which indicates the ratio of the firm's earnings before interest and taxes to its total interest payments. A high times interest earned ratio means that the firm should be more capable of covering its debt payments. The earnings figure is before taxes, as all debt interest costs are paid before taxable income is calculated. Interest costs are thus categorized as a business expense.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Times_interest_earned)

[image]

1. What does "times" mean? Multiplication? Out of all [financial ratios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_ratio#Ratios), just this has "times".
2. "Times" what?
3. What does "Earned" refer to" The interest earned? Or EBITDA?

Comment: Has Stack become the new Gill/Madura book promotion web site?

Comment: why downvote? they sadden me....

Comment: The Wiki article explains it all.  And even if you can't  grasp its meaning, a simple google search would provide many explanations with examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ratio tells you the multiple of a company’s interest expenses that they are earning.

If the company’s annual interest expense is $100k, and they have earnings of $1 million, then they have *earned* 10 *times* their *interest* expense. The *times interest earned* ratio is 10.

Yes, the name is a little awkward, which is why this ratio is also called the *interest coverage ratio*, as it is a measure of how well a company is covering its interest obligations with earnings.